# Problem while solving question in infytq app

Tags: python, list

The problem is even the calculator should the answer write but it is wrong in the website.

## The problem Statement

ARS Gems Store sells different varieties of gems to its customers.

Write a Python program to calculate the bill amount to be paid by a customer based on the list of gems and quantity purchased. Any purchase with a total bill amount above Rs.30000 is entitled for 5% discount. If any gem required by the customer is not available in the store, then consider total bill amount to be -1.

Assume that quantity required by the customer for any gem will always be greater than 0.

Perform case-sensitive comparison wherever applicable.

```
#List of gems available in the store
gems_list=['Amber', 'Aquamarine', 'Opal', 'Topaz']
#Price of gems available in the store. gems_list and price_list have one-to-one correspondence
price_list=[4392, 1342, 8734, 6421]

#List of gems required by the customer
reqd_gems=['Amber', 'Opal', 'Topaz']
#Quantity of gems required by the customer. reqd_gems and reqd_quantity have one-to-one correspondence
reqd_quantity=[2, 1, 3]
bill_amount=calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity)
print(bill_amount)
```

I expect the output was 36781

This is the solution I came up with so far:

```py
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity):
    bill_amount = 0
    for i in range(0, len(reqd_gems)):
        if (reqd_gems[i] in gems_list) and reqd_quantity[i] > 0:
            for j in range(0, len(gems_list)):
                if gems_list[j] == reqd_gems[i]:
                    price = price_list[j]
                    break
            bill_amount = bill_amount + (price) * reqd_quantity[i]
            bill_amount_amt = bill_amount - (5 / 100) * bill_amount
        else:
            bill_amount = -1
            break
    return bill_amount
```

Comment: What result are you actually getting? What debugging have you done? And show a [mcve] of the problem. This isn't all the code.

Comment: `code I used`
`
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
    bill_amount=0
    for i in range(0,len(reqd_gems)):
        if (reqd_gems[i] in gems_list) and reqd_quantity[i]>0:
            for j in range(0,len(gems_list)):
                if gems_list[j] == reqd_gems[i]:
                    price = price_list[j]
                    break
            bill_amount = bill_amount+(price)*reqd_quantity[i]
            bill_amount_amt = bill_amount-(5/100)*bill_amount
        else:
            bill_amount = -1
            break
    return bill_amount`

Comment: @Rajeshwari I've edited my answer to add the 5% discount and the -1 rule. Does it work now..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to "match" the amount to the price of the same gem, is to create two dictionaries based on the corresponding lists.

try this:

```py
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity):
    price_dict = {gems_list[i]: price_list[i] for i in range(len(gems_list))}
    reqd_dict = {reqd_gems[i]: reqd_quantity[i] for i in range(len(reqd_gems))}

    try:
        bill = sum(price_dict[gem] * reqd_dict[gem] for gem in reqd_dict)
    except KeyError:
        return -1

    if bill > 30000:
        bill = 0.95*bill
    return bill

#List of gems available in the store
gems_list=['Amber', 'Aquamarine', 'Opal', 'Topaz']
#Price of gems available in the store. gems_list and price_list have one-to-one correspondence
price_list=[4392, 1342, 8734, 6421]

#List of gems required by the customer
reqd_gems=['Amber', 'Opal', 'Topaz']
#Quantity of gems required by the customer. reqd_gems and reqd_quantity have one-to-one correspondence
reqd_quantity=[2, 1, 3]
bill_amount=calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity)
print(bill_amount)
```

Comment: @RajeshwariNadar well you edited the inputs in the question... I edited the answer to match the new inputs, does it work now?

Comment: reqd_quantity-[10],gems_list-['Moonstone', 'Sapphire', 'Quartz'],reqd_gems-['Ivory'],price_list-[3498, 1257, 5467]

reqd_quantity-[5, 8],gems_list-['Moonstone', 'Sapphire', 'Quartz'],reqd_gems-['Ivory', 'Quartz'],price_list-[3498, 1257, 5467]

Showing Wrong for following test case

Comment: @RajeshwariNadar I edited again, now with 5% discount over 30000 and -1 if gem not in stock

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
bill_amount=0
#Write your logic here
for i in range (0, len(reqd_gems)):
    if((reqd_gems[i] in gems_list) and reqd_quantity[i]>0):
        for j in range (0, len(gems_list)):
            if(gems_list[j] == reqd_gems[i]):
                price= price_list[j]
                bill_amount = bill_amount+(price*reqd_quantity[i])
                break
            
        else:
            bill_amount = -1
            break
if(bill_amount>30000):
    bill_amount = bill_amount - (5/100*bill_amount)
return bill_amount
```

Comment: This will give you the correct answer , You only did one mistake in your solution that is wrong placement of the line where discount is done . And the expected answer should be 34941.95 after 5% DISCOUNT

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

```
def calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems,reqd_quantity):
    bill_amount=0

    for i in reqd_gems:
        if reqd_quantity[reqd_gems.index(i)]>0 and i in gems_list:
            amount=reqd_quantity[reqd_gems.index(i)]*(price_list[gems_list.index(i)])
            bill_amount=bill_amount+amount
            if int(bill_amount)>30000:
                bill_amount=bill_amount-0.05*(bill_amount)
        
        else:
            bill_amount=-1
            break
    
    return bill_amount
```

#List of gems available in the store
gems_list=["Emerald","Ivory","Jasper","Ruby","Garnet"]

#Price of gems available in the store. gems_list and price_list have one-to-one correspondence
price_list=[1760,2119,1599,3920,3999]

#List of gems required by the customer
reqd_gems=["Ivory","Emerald","Garnet"]

#Quantity of gems required by the customer. reqd_gems and reqd_quantity have one-to-one correspondence
reqd_quantity=[3,10,12]

bill_amount=calculate_bill_amount(gems_list, price_list, reqd_gems, reqd_quantity)
print(bill_amount)